# Why does my program return a bunch of random numbers?

Tags: c

I'm making a program to convert seconds to time in HH:MM:SS format but it returns 6422296,6422292,6422288 every time

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(){
    int sec,h,m,s; 
    scanf("%d", &sec);
 
    h = (sec/3600);
    m = ((sec-(3600*h))/60);
    s = ((sec-(3600*h)-(60*m)));

    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", &h, &m, &s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the ampersands before your variables in the printf statement.  That only applies to scanf, not printf.

Comment: `m = s / 60; s %= 60; h = m / 60; m %= 60;` with modulo operator `%`: remainder after division.

Comment: You should turn up compiler warnings. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. That should show some warnings about parameter type mismatch for format specifier `%d`.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to print the addresses of the variables:

```
printf("%d,%d,%d\n", &h, &m, &s);
```

You want to print their values:

```
printf("%d,%d,%d\n", h, m, s);
```